How to draw Pascal's Triangle mod 3 with Tikz
I am writing about a math problem in which Pascal's Triangle is being studied (mod 3). Therefore I took the code from another thread in which the first n lines of Pascal's triangle were calculated. Then I found the intcalc package from which I took the \intcalcMod{}{} command so that it just returned the value (mod 3). My code ended up looking like this :
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{intcalc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\binomialCoefficient[2]{%
    % Store values 
    \c@pgf@counta=#1% n
    \c@pgf@countb=#2% k
    %
    % Take advantage of symmetry if k > n - k
    \c@pgf@countc=\c@pgf@counta%
    \advance\c@pgf@countc by-\c@pgf@countb%
    \ifnum\c@pgf@countb>\c@pgf@countc%
        \c@pgf@countb=\c@pgf@countc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Recursively compute the coefficients
    \c@pgf@countc=1% will hold the result
    \c@pgf@countd=0% counter
    \pgfmathloop% c -> c*(n-i)/(i+1) for i=0,...,k-1
        \ifnum\c@pgf@countd<\c@pgf@countb%
        \multiply\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@counta%
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1%
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by1%
        \divide\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@countd%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
    \the\c@pgf@countc%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \n in {0,...,5} {
      \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
         \node at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {$\intcalcMod{\binomialCoefficient{\n}{\k}}{3}$};
      }
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It worked without the \intcalcMod{}{3} around the \binomialCoefficient{\n}{\k}, however now it gives this result:

How can this be fixed ?
Thank you for any help.

Welcome! Please can you make your code so it can be copy-paste-compiled? When I guess, I get an error. If I ignore the error, I don't get the output you show.

The \binomialcoefficient macro is not expandable: it has all the computations and can be used for printing the value, not for passing it for further computations.
You can do the computation and use the stored value to feed \intcalcMod.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{intcalc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\computebinomialCoefficient[2]{%
    % Store values 
    \c@pgf@counta=#1\relax% n
    \c@pgf@countb=#2\relax% k
    %
    % Take advantage of symmetry if k > n - k
    \c@pgf@countc=\c@pgf@counta
    \advance\c@pgf@countc by-\c@pgf@countb
    \ifnum\c@pgf@countb>\c@pgf@countc
        \c@pgf@countb=\c@pgf@countc
    \fi
    %
    % Recursively compute the coefficients
    \c@pgf@countc=1 % will hold the result
    \c@pgf@countd=0 % counter
    \pgfmathloop % c -> c*(n-i)/(i+1) for i=0,...,k-1
        \ifnum\c@pgf@countd<\c@pgf@countb
        \multiply\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@counta
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by1
        \divide\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@countd
    \repeatpgfmathloop
    %\the\c@pgf@countc%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \n in {0,...,5} {
      \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
         \computebinomialCoefficient{\n}{\k}%
         \node at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {$\intcalcMod{\value{pgf@countc}}{3}$};
      }
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I fixed all the wrongly placed % in the code.

You can use a different strategy, though:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \n in {0,...,5} {
      \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
         \node at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {$\xintexpr\xintiiBinomial{\n}{\k}/:3\relax$};
      }
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Look at the manual for xintexpr for more details.

Thank you so much for your help! I'd only used TeX for short solutions to math problems, so I was a little lost. : )

With lualatex
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,luacode}

\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
function  Coeff (n,k)
local Bnk = 1
 for i = 1,k do
    Bnk = (n-i+1)*Bnk / i
    end
 return  math.fmod(Bnk,3)
 end
\end{luacode}  
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0}
   \foreach \n in {0,...,8} {
      \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
     \node at (\k-\n/2,-\n) { \pgfmathprintnumber{\directlua{ tex.print(Coeff(\n,\k)) }}};
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Why compute so few?
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\namexdef[1]{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\nameuse[1]{\csname#1\endcsname}

\newcommand\BinomModThree[2]{\nameuse{binom_mod3.\the\numexpr#1.\the\numexpr#2.}}

% Compute a need binomial coefficient mod three.
% USE ONLY IF PRIOR PASCAL ROW KNOWN
% USE ONLY WITH 0<= #2 <= #1 and #1, #2 integers (or evaluate to integers)
\newcommand\ComputeBinomModThree[2]{%
    \namexdef{binom_mod3.#1.#2.}{%
      \ifnum\numexpr#2\relax=0 1%
      \else\ifnum\numexpr#2\relax=\numexpr#1\relax 1%
      \else\the\numexpr\BinomModThree{#1-1}{#2}+\BinomModThree{#1-1}{#2-1}%
      \fi\fi
    }%
    \ifnum\BinomModThree{#1}{#2}>2
      \namexdef{binom_mod3.#1.#2.}{\the\numexpr\BinomModThree{#1}{#2}-3}%
    \fi
}
% (this can be easily modified to compute Binom(n,k) modulo N for any N)

\begin{document}

\begin{center}% only to center horizontally on page
  \makebox[0pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \foreach \n in {0,...,50} { 
      \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
        \ComputeBinomModThree{\n}{\k} 
        \node at (\k-\n/2,-0.7*\n) {$\BinomModThree{\n}{\k}$}; 
      } 
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\end{document}



as (1+x)^3=1+x^3 mod 3 it is possible to set up a Pascal like recurrence from row N to row N+3. But I don't think this is worth the effort (many other things than the computations happen for the tikz picture to end up in the pdf).

actually I timed separately the computation of the coefficients and the drawing of the TikZ picture (once the coefficients have all been pre-computed up to n=50 in a prior nested foreach loop), and the ratio was about of 1to 160 !! So attempting to make the computations faster is senseless (I trust the code of my answer is fastest of all answers here attow anyhow).

when one computes all rows, row by row, it brings absolutely no advantage to use the N <- N-3, K <- {K,K-3} compared to N<-N-1, K<-{K,K-1}.  But despite my first comment I did waste the time to code the alternative recursion.. which is indeed more painful to implement because more special cases have to be handled.

about I trust the code of my answer is fastest of all answers here attow anyhow I tried to compare with the luacode solution but it is difficult because should one only keep \directlua{ Coeff(\n,\k) },  or \edef\x{\directlua{ tex.print(Coeff(\n,\k)) }}. In the latter case the lua code takes about exactly same time as the one of this answer to compute all coeffs up to n=50.  Half of this time is actually taken by the nested \foreach loops from which all contents are removed.
